# Using Node.js to access data from a running executable program

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a large program written in C# using Visual Studio that is running as a standalone executable complete with an extensive GUI interface. We want to add a web interface to the program in order to get most, if not all of the functionality available.

The first step I took was to add a web server to the C# executable and I linked in some web pages (html and css) and I was able to present some data as a test case and this worked.

We decided that it would be better to treat the standalone executable like a database where we would prefer to send requests to the get data and post data to store data.

I'm using Node.js framework and Express as my webserver. I have a number of web pages designed and I'm using javascript and some embedded javascript to render data on some of the web pages.

The issue I'm having is how do I process a selected route on one of my webpages to force the   the .js file that is processing the route to go out and access the executable program that is running on the same computer at this moment to both get and set data in the executable program and then present it back on the web page.

HTML code (test_data_02.ejs)

```
<input class="LSNButton1" type="button" style="color:black; background:green;" value="Test Button B" onclick="window.location.href = '/get_test_02b'" />
```

Javascript (Express) (main.js)

```
const { json } = require("express");

const express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    fs = require("fs"),
    homeController = require("./controllers/homeController"),
    errorController = require("./controllers/errorController"),
    data_entry_03 = require("./public/js/data_entry_03"),
    layouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(layouts);

app.use(express.static("public"));                          //tell the application to use the corresponding public folder to serve static files

app.use(express.urlencoded({                                //assists in reading body contents, parse incoming requests in url format
    extended: false
}));

app.use(express.json());                                    //assists in reading body contents, parse incoming requests in json format

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);


console.log("MAIN MAIN MAIN");                              //this only happens once on start up - this file is only executed on startup, everything is configured on startup

//MIDDLEWARE CODE
app.use((req, res, next) => {                               //this is a generic middleware function that will be called before any route is processed 
    homeController.middleWareFunction(req, res);            //process this function before moving on to next route that was selected
    //console.log(req.query);                                 //from the browser: http://localhost:3000?cart3&jack=5, this results in a request to /?cart=3&jack=5, how do i make a post for this
    console.log(`request made to: ${req.url}`);
    console.log("");
    next();
})

//app.use("/general_data", homeController.readDataFile);      //run this function for every request made to the path beginning with this route - it does not imply it is a middleware that will run on this route before the get 

//GET ROUTE CODE
app.get("/", homeController.showHome);                      //a specific route has been identified and the callback function assoicated with the particular route is specified
app.get("/specific_data", homeController.showSpecificData);
app.get("/general_data", homeController.showGeneralData);

app.get("/get_test_02b", homeController.getTest02B);
```

More Javascript (homeController.js)

I was hoping somewhere in 'getTest02B' or in 'getTestData02B' I would be able to send or request data from the executable program somehow. Maybe using a URL. I would obviously need to add code to my executable to process the requests to either send or receive data. I would  like to be able to process the data as JSON, XML, or text data in both directions. I just can't see the mechanism to perform this operation.

```
exports.getTest02B = (req, res) => {
    console.log("in exports.getTest02B");
    displayInformation(req.url, "URL");
    displayInformation(req.method, "METHOD");
    displayEmptyLine();

    getTestData02B(function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);

        res.send(data);
    });
};
```

One comment on this issue was that I needed to make a http request to the C#
program. I understand that Node.js allows several connections per server to
make HTTP requests.

I'm using the code below and it is not working.

```
const req = http.request('http://192.168.1.222/ListAlarms.html', (res) => {
console.log('STATUS:${res.statusCode}');
});

req.end;
```

When I run this code there appears to be no response from the C# program.

From the editing environment where I wrote the code above, if I select the URL and press CONTROL and CLICK I end up launching another browser with the data being displayed because the C# program is currently running. This implies to me that at least the URL in the http.request statement is good. Just to confirm the URL was working I ran the C# program in the debugger and I was able to break on receiving the URL. The URL is good but I just can't seem to access the C# program from the Node.js environment using the same URL. Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

I assume that once I'm able to generate a http.request from the Node.js environment I would be able to control the flow of data to and from the C# program.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Just make an HTTP request to your C# program. You've already modified it to have a built-in web server. You can either use node's built-in HTTP client library or use a higher-level library like node-fetch, axios or undici

Comment: "*treat the standalone executable like a database*" - well now your executable must expose a database interface instead of a web interface. What kind of API did you think of implementing?

Comment: I tried using XMLHttpRequest in my javascript code but it always resulted in an error. I realized that I wanted to make a http request to the C# program but the function I was using didn't work. I need to find the correct command.

Comment: I also tried ```request(`http://192.168.1.222:51111/ListAlarms.html', fucntion())) which also did not work. If I used the the URL mentioned in the command above in a web browser while my C# program was running as a web server I was able to serve the web page. I still don't see how I can get from Node.js to accessing the data in C# program.

Comment: "*I needed to make a http request to the C# program*" - it doesn't need to be HTTP, any protocol would work, but http might be the easiest.

Comment: "*I'm using the code below and it is not working.*" - `req.end` does nothing. You actually want to [call the method: `req.end();`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestenddata-encoding-callback).